# Eclipse keyboard shortcuts with Dvorak

Tags: eclipse, command, dvorak

I use Eclipse with Dvorak-QWERTY Commands (a Mac option). I am running OS 10.6. But when I press the command key, it does not revert back to the QWERTY keyboard but instead stays as Dvorak. This makes keyboard shortcuts a lot harder to use. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I solved this problem by learning where the shortcuts are on Dvorak (no remapping to QWERTY). It takes a bit of time but not too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Eclipse (or other program) supports remapping keyboard shortcuts, you can just go to remap the shortcut to the same physical key that originally was in QWERTY while your keyboard is in Dvorak, so it looks like the same shortcut but is actually mapped to a different key.

Otherwise, I'd just take the time to learn the shortcuts in Dvorak. It may be a pain at first but you'll be one more step towards being QWERTY-independent.

Comment: The problem is, some shortcuts are dependent on key location, like X, C and V for cut, copy and paste.

Comment: That's why I recommended remapping to the same *physical* key, so that the location remains constant while the logical key changes.